# Weight of box in a Lazy Vertical Grid - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to get my Lazy Vertical Grid to be working the way I have it in the non-JetpackCompose version. I have this keypad that contains buttons ranging from 0 to 9 and a clear button. The grid is 3 buttons wide, it starts with 1 to 9, the last column contains 0 and CLEAR, however the CLEAR buttons should be twice as wide as the other buttons. See this image from the non-Jetpack Compose version of my app:[image]

This is the code I currently have, note I just started working in jetpack compose so my knowledge is not that high compared to the other xml style.

```
LazyVerticalGrid(
            GridCells.Fixed(3),
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            itemsIndexed(keypadBtn + listOf("0", "CLEAR")) { _, keyTxt ->
                Box(
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .size(width = if(keyTxt == "CLEAR") 260.dp else 120.dp, height = 80.dp)
                        .padding(start = 5.dp, end = 5.dp, top = 5.dp, bottom = 5.dp)
                        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
                        .background(if (keyTxt == "CLEAR") Color.Gray else Color.White)
                        .weight(if (keyTxt == "CLEAR") 2f else 1f)
                        .clickable {
                            // Handle click action here
                        }
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = keyTxt,
                        color = if (keyTxt == "CLEAR") Color.White else Color.Black,
                        fontSize = 36.sp,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                    )
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Composable
fun NumberDemo() {
    val list = listOf("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "CLEAR")
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(3),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
    ) {
        items(list.size, span = { index ->
            val spanCount = if (index == list.size - 1) 2 else 1
            GridItemSpan(spanCount)
        }) { count ->
            Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center, modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(start = 5.dp, end = 5.dp, top = 5.dp, bottom = 5.dp)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
                .background(if (list[count] == "CLEAR") Color.Gray else Color.White)
                .clickable {
                    // Handle click action here
                }) {
                Text(
                    text = list[count],
                    color = if (list[count] == "CLEAR") Color.White else Color.Black,
                    fontSize = 36.sp,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]